# Remove logback console appender (or override pattern)

Tags: java, logging, logback

It happened that library contains some logback configurations that i can't remove or change. Basically that configs only introduce console appender

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p [%.15t] [%X{traceId}] [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.some" level="INFO"/>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

In my application i have own configs which declare file appender. But one day my thread names became longer than 15 symbols and i thought it will be great to display it full name but not ending.
Can i somehow override that patter to display full thread name or override whole appender with proper pattern?